# DHTMLX scheduler drop event issue

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

Scheduler Version: **v.3.3.11**

IE Version: **11.666 or Emulator IE11 windows 8.1 Update**

Windows: **10**

Jquery Version: **1.5**

I'm trying to display lightbox when drag ends but it's not working on IE specific version but it works on all other browsers and other IE browser versions.
I tried binding with ***onDragEnd*** & ***onBeforeEventChanged***, but both events are not getting triggered
But when I target IE browser to IE 9 everything, works fine , don't know what is causing the issue

Code as follow :

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onDragEnd", function(id, mode, e){
    console.log(id);
    scheduler.showLightbox(id);
}); 

scheduler.attachEvent("onBeforeEventChanged", function (event_object, native_event, is_new, original) {
 scheduler.showLightbox(event_object.event_pid);
});
```

when i run this code block from console directly

```
scheduler.showLightbox(12235654);
```

lightbox gets dispalyed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this issue can be solved in another way, except for installing a different version of IE. Since this is a very specific problem that is related to the browser version and not to DHTMLX Scheduler events.